# Can you reformat date parameter values in Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to transform the format of a date value that is passed to the query? I am trying to create a report that interfaces with a SAP back-end, but the query uses a different format for date objects. I need to take the selected date and reformat it to "yyyy.mm.dd" (including the quotes). Is this possible? I can do it as a textbox, but this is a bit ugly. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the parameter is passed to your sql in the dataset of your report,  you can change the expression.   For example, this is the default code

```
=Parameters!StartDate.Value
```

You can change it to, basically the expression is like vb code

```
="""" + Year(Parameters!StartDate.Value).ToString() + "." + Month(Parameters!StartDate.Value).ToString() + "." + Day(Parameters!StartDate.Value).ToString() + """"
```